# Exchange 2007 ignores whitelist (BypassedSenderDomains) when IP is found on a block list

Tags: exchange, spam, exchange-2007, spam-filter

On my Exchange 2007 machine I configured the IP block list provider to query

- zen.spamhaus.org
- bl.spamcop.net
- dnsbl.sorbs.net

some of our business contacts or on those lists and get blocked by Exchange. So I added their domains to the `BypassedSenderDomains` list:

```
[PS] C:\>Get-ContentFilterConfig | fl bypassedsenderdomains
BypassedSenderDomains : {domain1.com, domain2.com}
```

Unfortunately, they get blocked anyway, as you can see in the Agent Log:

```
P1FromAddress       Agent                       Event           Action          SmtpResponse                        Reason                                  ReasonData          Diagnostics
sender@domain1.com  Connection Filtering Agent  OnRcptCommand   RejectCommand   "550 5.7.1 Recipient not authorized your IP has been found on a block list" BlockListProvider   dnsbl.sorbs.net
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange isn't ignoring your setting. This happens because Connection filtering occurs before Content filtering. you'll need to add the sender's ip address to the IP Allow list.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997242(EXCHG.80,printer).aspx

Comment: Looking at the chart (thanks!), I assume there is now way to whitelist only emails from my business partners, if they are sending their emails through their ISPs mail relay server, which tens of thousands of people use?

Comment: It looks like you can create a Transport Rule to get around this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198251(v=exchg.150).aspx